# Find numbers in file 2 within a specified range in 1 file and then calculate the average value of another column within that range

Tags: search, awk, find, average

I've been trying to work this one out for weeks and I know it's a simple awk script, but I can't seem to make much headway. Any thoughts?

I have two .txt files that I am dealing with.

File 1 (Column 1 has the same value)-

```
1 1000 1
1 1003 3
1 1020 6
1 167999 5
1 167222 4
```

File 2 (Column 1 has the same value)-

```
1 1000 1050
1 167000 168000
```

I want to search for values in column 2 of file 1 that fall within the range specified in columns 2 and 3 of file 2. Then I want to find the average value of column 3 in file 1 within the now specified ranges, and output the list of average values. Any help is much appreciated as I am still new to the coding world!

Comment: and what is you trial ? Tip, start with reading file2, put info into arrays than read file1 and treat computation `awk '...' file2 file1`. file1 [second file read] could be line filterd by `FNR != NR` and file2 [first file read] filterd by `FNR=NR`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that should help you get started:

```
awk -v rangefile=file2 '
BEGIN {
    ranges=0
    while((getline < rangefile) > 0) {
        ++ranges
        low[ranges] = $2
        high[ranges] = $3
    }
}
{
    for(i = 1; i <= ranges; i++) {
        if($2 >= low[i] && $2 <= high[i]) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
END {
    for(i = 1; i <= ranges; i++) {
        print low[i], high[i]
    }
}
' file1
```

I didn't fill in the ... part, but I'm hoping the above covers the tricky part.  For ..., you could just use arrays for the sum and count similar to the arrays for low and high.  In the END block, you would repeat the for(i...) loop, and inside that loop print out whatever you wanted your output format to be.